# Find out java agent port inside the java application

Tags: java, javaagents

I am passing `-javaagent` VM argument parameter for prometheus JMX exporter with port as 0 so that port is assigned dynamically. Is there a way to find out the assigned port inside the Java application? I have tested this VM parameter and I can see from command line that  port is assigned for the java agent.

```
-javaagent:<path>/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.1-SNAPSHOT.jar=0:config.yml
```